# Editor config new line at start of file

Tags: code-formatting, editorconfig

Editor config has an option to insert blank lines at the end of the file. Is there something similar which allows for blank lines at the start of the file, ignoring shebang lines?

Comment: There is no such option currently, but if you are using Vim or Emacs you can try to add a custom option for yourself.